# change the ChromeOptions after i build the driver c# selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium on c# with ChromeDriver.
And I'm trying to change the download directory after I build the driver already on run time.
This example shows what I'm trying to do to change the download.default_directory after I build the driver,

```
        ChromeOptions chromeopt = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "c:\\first");
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeopt);
        chromeopt.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "c:\\second");
```

Comment: Can you please consider updating us the businesscase/usecase for which you are trying to change the download directory at run time? Thanks

Comment: ChromeOpt is something we are passing as constructor while instantiating our webdriver. Hope there is no straight way to to do this.

Comment: i need to login before i start to download and its takes sometime to login. and i need to build tree hierarchy folders. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using selenium the answer is no. Once we set up the default directory we cant change the download path.

But the work around is we can use C# inbuilt libraries to cut the downloaded file from the default download path to any other path. Below code might give some more idea.

```
Using system.IO;
                //Actual downloaded path
if(file.exist (@"c:\folder1\Test.jpg"))
{
   //move file to another directory
   file.Move(@"c:\folder2\Test.jpg")
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `download.default_directory` for any given driver (**ChromeDriver** in your case), it is set during the time WebDriver session is created which cannot be changed during runtime.

Even if you get hold of the capabilities of the created session, you won't be able to change the capabilities. So in simple terms the answer is **`No`**.

In-order to start with a new `download.default_directory` you must start a new session.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in my case i need to login before i download and its takes sometime to login. and i have to build lots of new folders, so its bad solution for me, maybe there are way to maybe construct  again the driver with the login cookies?

Comment: As per your Question `change the ChromeOptions after initialize the driver` I have provided the Answer. Now as per your comment, you can consider to login first, create the folders through your scripts before you start downloading. As per the latest GA release of Selenium 3.4.0 you may be able to get hold of the capabilities through `cookies` or `sessionID` but you cannot manipulate those.